# Voronoi diagram on surface of polyhedron

Tags: reference-request, cg.comp-geom

Does anyone know of work on computing the Voronoi diagram of a set of points on a polyhedron, where distance is measured by shortest paths on the surface?
I am particularly interested in convex polyhedra.  I have a vague memory that this has been explored, but my memory is too vague to locate any papers.  Thanks for pointers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use MMP k times, if you have k sites. For every face, you have to compute the additive weighted Voronoi diagram, and the overlay of k such diagrams still have linear complexity (because, it is just a planar additive weighted Voronoi idagram). As such, for a polytope with n faces and k sites, this takes $O(n^2 k \log n)$ time. You can use the latest monstrorisity by Sharir and Schriber and do it in $O(nk log n)$ time - but is not clear how to overlay the diagrams on every face. It is probably a good idea to look at their paper and see if they do something for this case.

As far as approximation, it is not hard to show that one can build a space decomposition of complexity $O(k/\epsilon^{O(1)} )$ such that given a query point, one can report the approximate nearest-neighbor on the polytope in $O( \log (k/\epsilon) )$ time. I think using some newer machinery, one can in fact also return the approximate distance in this time.

Comment: For those who don't know, MMP = Mitchell, Mount, Papamaditriou, "[The Discrete Geodesic Problem](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=33372)," 1987.

Comment: Thanks, Sariel! This seems correct, and explains why no one has written a separate paper on the topic.